# I want to set Dynamic SQL (Getting conversion failed error)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic

I want to set the following query into Query2 varchar(max) variable but I am getting the error

```
Conversion Failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT...
```

I think maybe I am missing something with regards to the +'s or /'s
I'm not sure exactly though.

```
Set @Query2 = 'SELECT tc.RequestID, cast(d2.CalendarYearNumber AS VARCHAR(4))' + 'P' + ' AS [Year],
    CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income Less than $10,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome10k-15k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $10,000 - $15,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome15k-20k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $15,000 - $20,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome20k-25k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $20,000 - $25,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome25k-30k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $25,000 - $30,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome30k-35k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $30,000 - $35,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome35k-40k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $35,000 - $40,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome40k-45k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $40,000 - $45,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome45k-50k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $45,000 - $50,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome50k-60k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $50,000 - $60,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome60k-75k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $60,000 - $75,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome75k-100k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $75,000 - $100,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome100k-125k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $100,000 - $125,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome125k-150k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $125,000 - $150,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome150k-200k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $150,000 - $200,000P],
    CAST(SUM(HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $200,000 or moreP],
    CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k]
     + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] 
     + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] 
     + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS TotalP 
INTO #tmpHHPct
FROM Fact.DemographicBlockGroup d
INNER JOIN Report.RequestMSTGeoID_CBG tc ON d.GeographyID = tc.GEOID
INNER JOIN dim.Date d2 ON d.DateSK = d2.DateSK
WHERE CurrentRecord = 1
    AND tc.RequestID =  ' + @RequestID + ' 
GROUP BY tc.RequestID, d2.CalendarYearNumber'
```

Comment: What is the data type of the variable @RequestID?

Comment: Could you please provide us with an http://sqlfiddle.com/ or at least some temp tables with sample data?

Comment: Why does this even need to be dynamic SQL? Why are you appending an input parameter instead of using *proper, strongly-typed parameters to protect yourself from SQL injection*? Anyway, the answer is simple - `@RequestID` is an integer, so SQL Server is trying to add `big string` to that value. You need to convert the variable to a string if you want to keep doing this in a scary, keep-your-resume-fresh kind of way. `+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @RequestID) +`.

Comment: If you like your job, and your company likes not having data breaches, please read [this](//sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx), [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/), and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/). Or if you don't like my style, do your own searching on `SQL injection`.

Comment: (You probably also need `+' + ''P'''+` instead of `+'P'+`.)

Comment: I really did not need to make this piece of code dynamic.  I did have to utilize dynamic sql in other areas. I'm now using sp_executesql. Thanks @AaronBertrand for pointing out the sql injection issues. I understand why using strongly typed variables is important.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming @RequestID is not a VARCHAR and some sort of numberic type like INT.

try this:

```
Set @Query2 = 'SELECT tc.RequestID, cast(d2.CalendarYearNumber AS VARCHAR(4))' + 'P' + ' AS [Year],
    CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income Less than $10,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome10k-15k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $10,000 - $15,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome15k-20k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $15,000 - $20,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome20k-25k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $20,000 - $25,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome25k-30k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $25,000 - $30,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome30k-35k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $30,000 - $35,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome35k-40k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $35,000 - $40,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome40k-45k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $40,000 - $45,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome45k-50k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $45,000 - $50,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome50k-60k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $50,000 - $60,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome60k-75k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $60,000 - $75,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome75k-100k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $75,000 - $100,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome100k-125k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $100,000 - $125,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome125k-150k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $125,000 - $150,000P],
    CAST(SUM([HHIncome150k-200k]) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $150,000 - $200,000P],
    CAST(SUM(HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS [Income $200,000 or moreP],
    CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k]
     + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] 
     + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] 
     + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(HHIncomeBelow10k + [HHIncome10k-15k] + [HHIncome15k-20k] + [HHIncome20k-25k] + [HHIncome25k-30k] + [HHIncome30k-35k] + [HHIncome35k-40k] + [HHIncome40k-45k] + [HHIncome45k-50k] + [HHIncome50k-60k] + [HHIncome60k-75k] + [HHIncome75k-100k] + [HHIncome100k-125k] + [HHIncome125k-150k] + [HHIncome150k-200k] + HHIncomeAbove200k) AS FLOAT) 
        AS TotalP 
INTO #tmpHHPct
FROM Fact.DemographicBlockGroup d
INNER JOIN Report.RequestMSTGeoID_CBG tc ON d.GeographyID = tc.GEOID
INNER JOIN dim.Date d2 ON d.DateSK = d2.DateSK
WHERE CurrentRecord = 1
    AND tc.RequestID =  ' + CAST(@RequestID AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' 
GROUP BY tc.RequestID, d2.CalendarYearNumber'
```